Importing Vertex groups with duplicated vertices
I'm working on a project to generate a mesh that was written in VSCode. When I create my vertex groups and run it directly in Blender, there is no issue.
However, when import the file as a .obj, it only gives me a few of the vertex groups.
When I dug a bit into this, it seemed that importing into Blender has issues with duplicated vertex groups that have overlapping indices. This is the case with .dae, .fbx or .obj.
Does anyone have a fix for this?
I'll add a couple of images to show an example of what is happening.
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.system = 'IMPERIAL'
bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.length_unit = 'INCHES'

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

def generateSinglePanel ():

    # Set height_width_thickness
    overall_width = 48
    overall_thickness = 0.375
    overall_height = 80

    # 1 meter = 39.3701 inches
    scale_factor = 39.3701

    # vertex positions on the (x,y,z) axis based from the measurements above.
    vertices = [
        (-overall_width / 2, -overall_thickness / 2, -overall_height / 2),
        (-overall_width / 2, -overall_thickness / 2, overall_height / 2),
        (overall_width / 2, -overall_thickness / 2, overall_height / 2),
        (overall_width / 2, -overall_thickness / 2, -overall_height / 2),
        (-overall_width / 2, overall_thickness / 2, -overall_height / 2),
        (-overall_width / 2, overall_thickness / 2, overall_height / 2),
        (overall_width / 2, overall_thickness / 2, overall_height / 2),
        (overall_width / 2, overall_thickness / 2, -overall_height / 2),
    ]

    edges = []

    faces = [
        (3, 2, 1, 0), (7, 6, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7),
        (0, 1, 5, 4), (2, 6, 5, 1), (7, 3, 0, 4)
    ]

    mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("PanelA_data")
    mesh_data.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
    mesh_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("PanelA", mesh_data)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(mesh_obj)


       # Vertex Grouping
    vertex_groups = [
        ('corner_bottom_left', (0, 4)),
        ('corner_bottom_right', (7, 3)),
        ('corner_top_right', (6, 2)),
        ('corner_top_left', (1, 5)),
        ('face_bottom', (0, 3, 4, 7)),
        ('face_right', (2, 3, 7, 6)),
        ('face_top', (1, 2, 6, 5)),
        ('face_left', (0, 1, 5, 4)),
        ('edge_bottom_front', (0, 3)),
        ('edge_right_front', (2, 3)),
        ('edge_top_front', (1, 2)),
        ('edge_left_front', (0, 1)),
        ('edge_top_back', (5, 6)),
        ('edge_left_back', (5,4 )),
    ]



    for group_name, indices in vertex_groups:
        group = mesh_obj.vertex_groups.new(name=group_name)
        group.add(indices, 0, 'REPLACE')


    # dimensions
    dimensions = mesh_obj.dimensions
    dimensions_in_inches = [(overall_width) / (scale_factor), (overall_thickness) / (scale_factor), (overall_height) / (scale_factor)]
    mesh_obj.dimensions = dimensions_in_inches

    # set location
    mesh_obj.location = (0, 0, 0)

generateSinglePanel()

